# Removing alphabets from column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
col A
28
45
67
A
67
C
D
78
89
```

I want to remove row containing characters(i.e) A, B, C...(can be any from A-Z)
I was able to remove A,B,C using the below code

```
new_df = df[(df['colA'] != 'A') & (df['colA'] != 'B') & (df['colA'] != 'C')]
```

I feel this is hardcoded as I know the column contains A,B,C. Some other column might contain F,G or something.
Any better approach to removing the characters from column.

**Note:- colA is of type object in dataframe**

**Output should be column containing numbers only and datatype should be changed from object to int**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `isalpha` for no numeric it will return `True` then we get the `~`

```
df = df[~df.colA.str.isalpha()]
Out[953]: 
  colA
0   28
1   45
2   67
4   67
7   78
8   89
```

Update method 2

```
df = df[pd.to_numeric(df['col A'],errors='coerce').notnull()]
Out[73]: 
  colA
0   28
1   45
2   67
4   67
7   78
8   89
```

Comment: The solution you mentioned does not work. Error message -TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: @flashspeedster check the update

Comment: The column name has space in between to 2 words(col A)- so  I am not sure if df.colName works. Can you help on this?

Comment: @flashspeedster you can use `df[["col A"]]` for such a case

Comment: @flashspeedster update again